# Email notification when someone add a new member to a task in a Microsoft List

Tags: sharepoint-online, outlook, power-platform, microsoft-lists, email-notification

I'm a beginner in Power Automate and I need someone support in the following topic?

I found this online, it's kind of similar with my topic but I don't know what to adjust
https://www.office365notes.com/2022/05/how-to-get-list-item-changes-using-power-automate.html

I have a Microsoft List created with the following fields ( Title, team_members, status ). The following flow is triggered when an item or file is modified in that list. For example I want to send the notification via mail or Teams, when someone add a new member to that list.

Appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I understand that when some fields changed in the list, a  notification will be sent.

Instead of Power Automate, you could use Alert me to achieve this.

[image]

[image]